# HTML vs JSON data in ajax response

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to load some data in frontend and show them.
One choice is to get data as JSON object and make HTML elements from them and the other way is to get HTML data from backend.

what are pros and cons of these two methods?
I'm using different clients such as mobile app and a website

Comment: There is no standard that defines this. (Your example of JSON is, however, invalid).

Comment: I mean better performance by standards!
Am I supposed to make table by javascript or server-side?
javascript increases the page size and server-side handling increases data size transferred via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would find you would have more control over the data if you sent properly formatted JSON data to the client-side script.  However, there are times when sending structured HTML would be necessary as well.  There is not a standard, per se, but I would lean toward sending JSON.  Depending upon your server-side language, you probably have a tool at your disposal to convert your server-side array into JSON, for example, in PHP you would use json_encode().  Hope this helps!

Think about your project, and, choose the way that you feel would perform the best and be the easiest to maintain.  If it doesn't work, try it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what John Shipp said.

There is no right or wrong way of doing things, nor is there a "standard" form. It's an architectural decision you need to make, taking into consideration how you want to a) generate your rendered output, and b) any manipulation you may want to do to it client-side.

If you're only concern is rendering rows into a table, and you have code server-side that already generates the correctly formatted HTML output, then just send it as HTML rows. Why write more code client-side that then has to then render an array of objects (JSON) into a table if you don't need to? The more code you write, the more places something can break.

On the other hand, if you first need to manipulate the data being displayed, or maybe have multiple places to render/use the data that goes into the table, then send it to the client as an array of objects and use Javascript or a templating framework of some description to render it into the table.

In terms of performance, I'd simply say "don't worry". The differences between each process will be negligible from a user's point of view. And I think for data size it's not worth worrying about either. The exception is when you start talking about Megabytes of data being send to the client, in which case you may want to consider changing your overall data processing and architecture - e.g. providing better filters, so less data at a time is send to the client - if that's appropriate for your design.